# Initialize decimal with literal

Tags: c++, decimal

I've got Decimal class which implements decimal floating point arithmetic. It can be initialized with an integral arithmetic type or a fractional digit stored as a string. Build-in floating point types are deliberately avoided because of their approximative nature. Such approach works well but fractional digits coded as strings look awkward. Is it possible to use somehow C++ literals to build strings (or binary representation) behind the scene?

```
Decimal a{"1.254684987"}; // current initialization
Decimal b{1.254684987_dec}; // desired way
```

Answer (score 5):

Given that you already have a c'tor taking a C-string, simply writr something like

```
Decimal operator "" _dec(const char* c){
    return Decimal{c}; // Assuming an explicit c'tor
}

auto whatever = 12.3_dec;
```

Of course, you need a C++11 compiler for this to work.

Comment: Wouldn't that work on C++11?

Comment: @DanielH yep, fixed

Comment: What's the name for this syntax?

Comment: @ibug in standardese, *raw literal operator*

Comment: @iBug More details are available [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal "User-defined literals at cppreference").

Comment: @DanielH I have that site in my bookmark. Anyway thank you.

Comment: oh... the case where you imagine an imaginary syntax that would just work for you and then you find out it isn't imaginary after all. If only there would be more of those moments...